# Multiple vendors Misfortune Cookie Router Authentication Bypass Exploit

Tags: ida, disassembly, firmware

I am working on an exploit over a month now I have a problem and cannot go further.

here is the link of the exploit:

https://gist.github.com/doorbash/f454c698f192a0e5d1bf4da9c6869b67

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39739

## Description:

Misfortune Cookie is a critical vulnerability that allows an intruder to remotely take over an Internet router and use it to attack home and business networks.With a few magic cookies added to your request you bypass any authentication and browse the configuration interface as admin, from any open port.

‌By sending **`Cxxx=yyy`** cookie to the router web interface **`yyy`** will be saved at memory address **`xxx * 0x28 + Offset`**.If we find **`Authentication Enable/Disable boolean address`** and **`offset`** we can add data for this firmware to the exploit's target list and bypass the authentication by sending the right cookie.

## How I analyzed the firmwares:

The firmware I analyzed at first is **TP-Link 8901G V3 3.0.1 Build 100901 Rel.23594**. [download it here](http://dl.2dclp.ir/doorbash.ir/mce/3.0.1%20Build%20100901%20Rel.23594) and run `binwalk -e V3 3.0.1 Build 100901 Rel.23594` then open the largest file in extracted directory using IDA by selecting `mipsb` as the cpu architecture and `0x80020000` for base address.

If you search for **Do not need** string using Alt+T keys you will find a **sb XXXX($gp)**
at the very first lines of the code you realize the **li $gp,YYYYY** instruction. the authentication address will be located by adding **XXXX and YYYYY** which in this case will be **0x803E1829**

Now we must discover how `Cookie: CNNNN=MMM;` alter memory contents:
if you search for "soapaction" using Alt+T you will find this:

[image]

Go to the sub process highlighted by red color.

[image]

Now consider the number 0x6b28 as **`A = 0x6B28`**

Now back and toward up:

[image]

Now go to the top sub process:

[image]

you will find this:

[image]

now **`B = 0xA44`**, **`C = 0x1887C`** and **`D = 0x8041877C`**.

and **`MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x16B88`** (I don't have any idea why but it works)

Now **`OFFSET = A - B + C + D - MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x80420554`**

now call **`info(calc(0x8041877C,0x1887c,0xa44,0x6B28,0x16b88),0x803E1829)`** or **`info(0x80420554,0x803E1829)`** in [util.py](http://dl.2dclp.ir/doorbash.ir/mce/util.py) I attached the output is **`,107367749,13`** which is the data we need for this firmware in the exploit.

the process is very similar (and different and also easier in the **TP-Link W8961ND V3 120830** [download it here](http://dl.2dclp.ir/doorbash.ir/mce/TD-W8961ND_V3_120830_FI)

[image]

```
AuthenticationAddress = 0x803605B4
A = 0x6B28
B = 0x0 (move    $a0, $s1)
C = 0x17E38
D = 0x804234C8
MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x16B88
OFFSET = A-B+C+D-MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x8042B2A0
```

We call **`info(0x8042B2A0,0x803605B4)`** in [util.py](http://dl.2dclp.ir/doorbash.ir/mce/util.py) and output is **`,107353414,36`** which is tested on real device and works.

## THE PROBLEM IS:

for **TD_W961ND_V3_140305** [download it here](http://dl.2dclp.ir/doorbash.ir/mce/TD-W8961ND_V3_140305) the firmware has **"Do not need"** and **"soapacation"** texts but IDA cannot find the pointing addresses to these strings.I could not find out why.

The modifications and bug fixes for this according to [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TD-W8961ND_V3.html#Firmware) is :

1. **Add the security mechanism.**
2. Fixed the problem router's time can't synchronize from PC successfully.
3. Banned accessing the firmware upgrading page from WAN.
4. Fixed the problem that router failed to upload rom-0(Backup configuration).
5. Solved the problem that the login interface can't save the password correctly in Chrome and Firefox.
6. Solved the problem that we can’t visit CPE using “IP:Port” after we set up Virtual Server.
7. Forbidden access to the device through http://wan/lan ip/ or http://wan/lan ip/xxx.htm.
8. Fixed other bugs and problems.

I am not sure if the security mechanism (#1) is what is making this issue or not.

I also tried to compare 100901, 120830 and 140305 using binwalk entropy:

## binwalk -E -J 120830 140305 100901

## 100901:

[image]

## 120830:

[image]

## 140305:

[image]

I know somethings wrong with **140305** (unusual wave forms at left) but could not come across any findings.

## Update 1:

Here is how memory address `0x800D53BC` looks like in my IDA:

[image]

Any idea or tip about how to fix this mess?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TP-LINK](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TD-W8961ND_V3.html#Firmware) the misfortune cookie was fixed only in firmware version TD-W8961ND_V3_150707. So, the TD_W961ND_V3_140305 is also vulnerable.

Since it is a binary file you may not analyse the code part dealing with the `soapaction` string, but here is what I found for firmware 140305:

[image]

UPDATE!

You can find the "Do not need" string at `0x801a015a`. For some reasons it is mips16 code and was referenced only from the command table as the `pswauthen` command handler. So, you have to change the code representation to mips16 with `alt+g` at the start of the handler and then press `c`.

[image]

Comment: Please see Update 1 in the question. thanks.

Comment: I don't know why IDA could not found ASCII in your case, but you can use 'a' (create ASCII) to create strings or you may create a simple script, which does this job.

Comment: Thanks, what about "Do not need" string? any idea why there is no pointing address to it?

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Comment: I saw it unfortunately I could not do what you did in update. IDA 6.8 still shows garbage, but well done I will set it as best answer when I worked on it again and managed to do it, thanks for your time. What version of IDA you got?